# add class in ul >li when load page in angular4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I try add Class in ul li  when load page in angular4 but any class has add in li.. for example I have this code in html:

```
<ul class="pagination">
   <button class="previous" (click)="previous()">Previous</button>
    <button class="next" (click)="next()">Next</button>
    <li  *ngFor="let x of k" class='page-item'  (click)='addClass(x)'>{{x}}</li>
</ul>
```

I try in function ngOnInit and in constructor add class but any class has added  :

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('1');
  $('.page-item').first().addClass('test');
}
```

and I try with document.ready but also result .. in console 1 is display but class is not add

Comment: You should have a look in to angular's renderer2 https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/ removes most of the need for jquery

Comment: For my example @Directive({   }) how to add class page-item ik selector directive or add for example <li testselec ...> and in @Directive({ selector: '[testselec]' }) !!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what you are trying to do is done via a `[ngClass]`. You can match the page number to the number for the current page. Here is a [working example](https://angular-wk4lqi.stackblitz.io).  If you find yourself using jQuery selectors be careful because this can take you outside of the event lifecycle and cause larger issues in your application.